# Pseudo coefficients and orbital integrals

Tags: reductive-groups, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I am looking for a reference/idea, how this passage from Labesse's Snowbird Lecture "Introduction to endoscopy" pg.5 can be explained:

> "We shall denote by $f_\pi$ a pseudo-coefficient for $\pi$, although it is highly non
>   unique. But as regards invariant harmonic analysis this plays no role. In
>   particular the orbital integrals are independent of the choice of the pseudocoefficient;
>   they are also independent of the choice of the Haar measure on
>   $G(F)$ but one has to use the canonical measure on the compact torus $G
> (F)$.
>   The orbital integrals of $f_\pi$ are easily computed for 
>    regular semisimple:
>   $$O_\gamma(f_\pi) =\begin{cases} \Theta_\pi(\gamma), & \gamma \mathrm{ elliptic}, \newline 0, &\mathrm{else},\end{cases} $$
>   where $\Theta_\pi(\gamma)$ is the character of $\pi$."

Here $G$ is a reductive group over a local field $F$ and $\pi$ a squareintegrable representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existence of pseudo-coefficients for square-integrable representations (and the link with character values of the representations) is stated and proved in

D. Kazhdan, Cuspidal geometry of $p$-adic groups.
J. Analyse Math. 47 (1986), 1–36.

Comment: I have seen this reference, in fact Labesse gives it himself. The existence is not the issue. What I want to understand/reference is the statement about the orbital integral. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: You also have the exact statement on the link bewteen orbital integral of a pseudo-coefficient and the character of the representation in Kazhdan's paper.

Comment: Okay, I was searching the document for keywords, probably not the correct ones;) I will have a more careful look. Thank you.

Comment: I find Kazhdan's paper difficult to read !

Comment: I went back again. It is theorem K on page 7.